# What is the purpose of $.jgrid.useJSON = true?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm saw this line a lot but can't find an answer:

```
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;
```

What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I include jqGrid in the following way

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/json2.js"></script>
```

So one should first include `grid.locale-en.js` which defines `$.jgrid`, then you can set `$.jgrid.useJSON` and `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api` and the later implementation of jqGrid in `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` will use the settings.

The option `$.jgrid.useJSON` will be used in `$.jgrid.parse` for parsing JSON strings either with `JSON.parse` or with `eval`.

To be exact the method `$.jgrid.parse` will be used not so frequently. Mostly two cases are relevant:

1. parsing of input `datastr` in case if the value of `datastr` has "string" type and `datatype: "jsonstring"`
2. parsing of `postData.filters` (the filter parameter used with local datatype and for advanced searching)
3. parsing JSON response from the server for subgrids in case of `subgridtype: "json"`
4. inside of `jqGridImport` method implementation

So the usage of `$.jgrid.useJSON = true;` is recommended, but it will influence the performance of your program probably not really because the most important cases of JSON parsing will be made typically by jQuery internally (typically by `jQuery.ajax`) and not by jqGrid code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into sources makes all clean:

```
parse : function(jsonString) {
  ...
  return ($.jgrid.useJSON===true && typeof (JSON) === 'object' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function') 
    ? JSON.parse(js) 
    : eval('(' + js + ')');
}
```

So basically it says:

*To parse a JSON string use JavaScript `JSON` API if possible instead of `eval`*